# Divide the vector column of a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, vector

Suppose the matrix

```
X = np.array([[ 1,  2,  3],
              [ 4,  5,  6],
              [ 7,  8,  9],
              [10, 11, 12]])
```

and the vector `divisor = [5, 10, 15]`. Is there a method using `numpy` to divide the first column of `X` by `divisor[0]`, the second column of `X` by `divisor[1]` and the second column of `X` by `divisor[3]`?

Comment: Have you tried `X / divisor`?

Comment: @Chris Ok, it works! And if I want to divide the lines, I have to do (X.T / divisor).T. Is there a better solution?

Comment: What do you mean divide the _lines_?

Comment: @Chris Instead of dividing the column as in the question, I want to divide the line of the same matrix. A more appropriate vecteur might be `dividor = [3, 2, 6, 9]`

Comment: `X / np.reshape(divisor, (-1, 1))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply divide them and let numpy take care of broadcasting:

```
X/divisor
```

output:

```
[[0.2 0.2 0.2]
 [0.8 0.5 0.4]
 [1.4 0.8 0.6]
 [2.  1.1 0.8]]
```

And if you want to divide the rows (instead of columns) use:

```
X/divisor[:,None]
```

Which adds a dimension to divisor so numpy can correctly broadcast it.